# is there such thing as sub-widgets/ hierarchy of widgets in databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am creating some widgets for dropdown in databricks.

For example

```
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Country', defaultValue ='United Kingdom', choices = [USA', 'France', 'Spain', 'italy']

country = dbutils.widgets.get('Country')
```

Then I want to have another widget like this for cities

```
dbutils.widgets.multiselect('Cities', defaultValue = '', choices = ['London', 'Paris', 'Edinburgh', 'Barcelona', 'Madrid']
```

Ideally I want it to be where if I choose `UK` as the country then the only remaining options for cities dropdown should be `London` and `Edinburgh`.

Also is there a way to get rid of the default widget value? when I put an empty string it says the empty string should be one of the `choices`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `if:..elif:..else` statement along with dropdown widget to achieve the requirement. Below is the code.

**Code:**

```py
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Country', defaultValue ='United Kingdom', choices = ['USA', 'France', 'Spain', 'Italy','United Kingdom'])
country = dbutils.widgets.get('Country')

if country == 'United Kingdom':
    dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Cities', defaultValue='London', choices = ['London', 'Edinburgh'])
elif country == 'France':
    dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Cities', defaultValue='Paris', choices = ['Paris'])
elif country == 'Spain':
    dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Cities', defaultValue='Barcelona', choices = ['Barcelona', 'Madrid'])
else:
    dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='Cities', defaultValue='', choices = [''])
```

**Output:**
[image]

> is there a way to get rid of the default widget value? when I put an empty string it says the empty string should be one of the 'choices'

`defaultValue` argument is an essential argument for dropdown and the value mentioned in defaultValue is to be part of choices.

Comment: The above two solutions work but the multiselect widget type is causing an issue. 
city = dbutils.widgets.get("Cities")
country = dbutils.widgets.get("Country")
print(country)
print(city)

this code will print the country and if you have previously selected a city e.g. 'London' and you choose the next country to be france until you deselect 'London' it wil still print in the 'city' variable Paris, London

Comment: Try dropdown instead of multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your country and their cities as a key value pair

```
countries_book = {
    "United Kingdom": ["London","Edinburgh"],
    "France": ["Paris"],
    "Spain": ["Barcelona","Madrid"]
}
```

1. Create a Dropdown widget using this countries_book keys

```
countries = list(countries_book.keys())
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="Country", defaultValue=countries[0], choices=countries)
```

2. Now use the selected country, fetch the cities according and use it with the multi select widget

```
selected_country = dbutils.widgets.get("Country")
cities = countries_book[selected_country]

dbutils.widgets.multiselect("Cities", defaultValue=cities[0], choices=cities)
```

***Output:***

[image: dbutils dropdown and multiselect]